# UserAssertion missing assertion and dont know where to get it

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, azure-active-directory

So I have the following code, which I am trying to use to get an access token on behalf of a user to gather information from the graph api.

```
            config.Log.WriteLine(LogLevel.Full, "Gathering OAuth Tokens for " + config.Username + " at " + config.Authority);
            try
            {
                AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(config.Authority);

                ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(config.AppKey, config.AppSecret);

                ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(config.AppKey, config.AppSecret);
                UserAssertion ua = new UserAssertion(//WHAT IS THIS & HOW DO I GET IT,
                                                    "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
                                                    config.Username);

                Task<AuthenticationResult> re = ac.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", cc.ClientId, ua);
                while(!re.IsCompleted)
                {
                    re.Wait();
                }
                oauthTokenCache = new OauthTokenCache(re.Result);            
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", oauthTokenCache.authHeader);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Aquire Access Token Exception: " + e);
                throw;
            }
```

But I have no idea where/what the [UserAssertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.userassertion?view=azure-dotnet) property "[assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.userassertion.assertion?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_UserAssertion_Assertion)" is meant to come from? The assertion Type is also a mystery, I cant find a list of the ok types, but in all the examples i've seen online they seem to use the one i have put in, but dont really help me get the assertion itself.
Any Help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a jwt bearer token that you'll get from your `HttpContext`

```
var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

//Get the access token used to call this API
string token = await httpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
//We are passing an *assertion* to Azure AD about the current user
//Here we specify that assertion's type, that is a JWT Bearer token
string assertionType = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer";

var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(token, assertionType, userName);
```

Check this guide for the full flow: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-on-behalf-of-aspnet-core

Of course I'm assuming you are using MVC. You can also get it from the authorization context https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, Don't suppose you could explain how to get it from the authorization context, as I am already using one , and not using an HttpContext so that would seem the sensible option, but i cannot find any methods which get me this token?